# How to get the values between two values in a col?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a history data like this

```
hist = pd.DataFrame({'date':['Jan1','Jan2', 'Jan3', 'Jan4'], 'Items':[['A','V'], ['D','C'],['F','X'],['Q','H']]})
```

[image]

another consumption table like this

```
consume = pd.DataFrame({'date':['Jan2','Jan4'], 'values':[100, 50]})
consume['delta'] = consume['values'].diff()
```

| date | values | delta |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan2 | 100 | NaN |
| Jan4 | 50 | -50 |

Between the beginning of date Jan2 and Jan4, I have decreased 50, and I want to extract all the items between Jan2 and Jan3 (Not Jan4, because items in Jan4 is happening during the date, but the values are collected in the beginning of the date)

The final desired table is

| date | values | delta | item_consumed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan2 | 100 | NaN | NaN |
| Jan4 | 50 | -50 | [D,C,F,X] |

How should I approach this problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

To do this, you can divide group by whether hist is in consume or not, then sum the values in the Item column for each group. After merging the results, you can shift the values by one.

```
grp = hist['date'].isin(consume['date']).cumsum()
df = hist.groupby(grp).agg({'date': 'first','Items': 'sum'}).rename_axis('')
out = consume.assign(item_consumed=consume.merge(df, how='left')['Items'].shift())
```

`out`

```
    date    values  delta   item_consumed
0   Jan2    100     NaN     None
1   Jan4    50      -50.0   [D, C, F, X]
```

**Intermediate**

`hist` & `grp`

```
        hist            grp
    date    Items   
0   Jan1    [A, V]      0 
1   Jan2    [D, C]      1
2   Jan3    [F, X]      1
3   Jan4    [Q, H]      2
```

`df`

```
    date    Items
0   Jan1    [A, V]
1   Jan2    [D, C, F, X]
2   Jan4    [Q, H]
```